# How to define topology in Castalia-3.2 for WBAN

Tags: simulator, omnet++, topology

- How can defined topology in Castalia-3.2 for WBAN ?
- How can import topology in omnet++ to casalia ?
- where the topology defined in default WBAN scenario in Castalia?
  with regard
  thanks

Comment: what do you mean by topology? [the manual](https://forge.nicta.com.au/docman/view.php/301/592/Castalia+-+User+Manual.pdf) says that you should use the `SN.deployment` parameter (see page 15).

Comment: I mean create mesh topology and defined node communication...defined node in range of each other to create mesh network and change the nod communication.

Comment: I want to defined which node send packet to which node...for example: node 1 send packets to node 2 and 4.and node 2 and 4 send packets to sink (node0)

Answer (score 0):

Topology of a network is an abstraction that shows the structure of the communication links in the network. It's an abstraction because the notion of a link is an abstraction itself. There are no "real" links in a wireless network. The communication is happening in a broadcast medium and there are many parameters that dictate if a packet is received or not, such as  the power of transmission, the path loss between transmitter and receiver, noise and interference, and also  just luck. Still, the notion of a link could be useful in some circumstances, and some simulators are using it to define simulation scenarios. You might be used to simulators that you can draw nodes and then simply draw lines between them to define their links. This is not how Castalia models a network.

**Castalia does not model links between the nodes, it models the channel and radios to get a more realistic communication behaviour**.

Topology is often confused with deployment (I confuse them myself sometimes). Deployment is just the placement of nodes on the field. There are multiple ways to define deployment in Castalia, if you wish, but it is not needed in all scenarios (more on this later). People can confuse deployment with topology, because under very simplistic assumptions certain deployments lead to certain topologies. Castalia does not make these assumptions. Study [the manual](https://github.com/boulis/Castalia) (especially chapter 4) to get a better understanding of Castalia's modeling.

After you have understood the modeling in Castalia, and you still want a specific/custom topology for some reason then you could play with some parameters to achieve your topology at least in a statistical sense. Assuming all nodes use the same radios and the same transmission power, then the path loss between nodes becomes a defining factor of the "quality" of the link between the nodes. In Castalia, you can define the path losses for each and every pair of nodes, using a pathloss map file.

```
SN.wirelessChannel.pathLossMapFile = "../Parameters/WirelessChannel/BANmodels/pathLossMap.txt"
```

This tells Castalia to use the specific path losses found in the file instead of computing path losses based on a wireless channel model. The deployment does not matter in this case. At least it does not matter for communication purposes (it might matter for other aspects of the simulation, for example if we are sampling a physical process that depends on location).

In our own simulations with BAN, we have defined a pathloss map based on experimental data, because other available models are not very accurate for BAN. For example the, lognormal shadowing model, which is Castalia's default, is not a good fit for BAN simulations. We did not want to enforce a specific topology, we just wanted a realistic channel model, and defining a pathloss map based on experimental data was the best way.

I have the impression though that when you say topology, you are not only referring to which nodes **could** communicate with which nodes, but which nodes **do** communicate with which nodes. **This is also a matter of the layers above the radio (MAC and routing)**. For example it's the MAC and Routing that allow for relay nodes or not.

Note that in Castalia's current implementations of 802.15.6MAC and 802.15.4MAC, relay nodes are **not allowed**. So you can not create a mesh topology with these default implementations. Only a star topology is supported. If you want something more you'll have to implemented yourself.